# Await long-running task on original context

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, asynchronous, async-await

I have some objects that start long-running background work on construction and would like to await their completion on `IAsyncDisposable`.

I would like to run this work on the thread pool.  I am trying to figure out the safest way to do this while avoiding deadlocks. I cannot figure out how to use `JoinableTaskFactory` and/or `JoinableContext` to do this.

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading;

public class Worker : System.IAsyncDisposable

{
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts;
    private Task _work;
    private JoinableTask _workSafe;

    public Worker()
    {
        _cts = new();
        // goes on the thread pool. But no way to join/await on that thread later?
        _work = Task.Run(() => DoWorkAsync(_cts.Token));
        
        // using the library I can await on same thread later. But it
        //    executes on the same thread as the constructor (undesirable)
        //    according to the documentation
        var ctx = new JoinableTaskContext();            
        _workSafe = ctx.Factory.RunAsync(() => DoWorkAsync(_cts.Token), JoinableTaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    private async Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(50);
        }
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
        // VS says this is unsafe
        await _work;
        // But this is safe
        await _workSafe;
        _cts.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"would like to await their completion on IAsyncDispose"* <= What's the `IAsyncDispose`? Do you mean `IAsyncDisposable`?

Comment: What do you mean "VS says this is unsafe"?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yes.

Comment: @StephenCleary Green squigglies with Warning VSTHDR003  "Avoid awaiting or returning a Task representing work that was not started within your context as that can lead to deadlocks. Start the work within this context, or use JoinableTaskFactory.RunAsync to start the task and await the returned JoinableTask instead. https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-threading/blob/main/doc/analyzers/VSTHRD003.md

Comment: Are you writing some extension for Microsoft's Visual Studio, or you just want to know how to use these components (`JoinableTaskFactory`, `JoinableContext`) in any type of .NET application?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias the latter. I have successfully used `JoinableTaskFactory` to get onto the main thread when needed for WPF apps (instead of `Dispatcher.Invoke`). But using them to avert this type of warning here I can't figure out.

Comment: @Adam I hope that you'll get an answer, because I would like to know too. These types look quite obscure to me!